# Placing figures inside table with captions for each

Tags: tables

I try to place 2 by 2 figures in table with each having caption

I tried

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{subfigure}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{./img/1.png}\caption{Figure A}\label{fig:taba}\end{subfigure}&
\begin{subfigure}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{./img/1.png}\caption{Figure B}\label{fig:tabb}\end{subfigure}\\
\newline
\begin{subfigure}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{./img/1.png}\caption{Figure C}\label{fig:tabc}\end{subfigure}&
\begin{subfigure}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{./img/1.png}\caption{Figure A again}\label{fig:taba2}\end{subfigure}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table with figures}
\label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}
```

but this gives error

```
[109] [110] <use ./img/1.png>
! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
\caption@hrule ->\hrule 
                        \@height \z@ 
l.888 ...nwidth]{./img/1.png}\caption{Figure A}
                                                  \label{fig:taba}\end{subfi...
```

Any help how to solve these? I checked many code blocks to place figures in table none works

Comment: why do you want them in a `table` so the outer caption is `table: 2` not `figure: 2` ?

Comment: @David that also works. I can place subfigures in a big figure

Comment: it isn't clear what you mean by "work" but if you put subfigures in a `table` environment then they will be kept in order with tables rather than figures, and the general caption is table rather than Figure, it's rather more normal to use a `figure` environment  (you can still use a`tabular` for layout of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{XX}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./img/1.png}
\captionof{figure}{Figure A}\label{fig:taba}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./img/1.png}   
        \captionof{figure}{Figure B}\label{fig:tabb}              \\
\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{./img/1.png}
\captionof{figure}{Figure C}\label{fig:tabc}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./img/1.png} 
        \captionof{figure}{Figure D}\label{fig:tabd}               
\end{tabularx}
\caption{A table with figures}
\label{tab:mytable}
    \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

or figures as sub figures?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./img/1.png}
    \caption{figure}\label{fig:taba}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./img/1.png}   
    \caption{Figure B}\label{fig:tabb}             
\end{subfigure}\\[1em]
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./img/1.png}
    \caption{Figure C}\label{fig:tabc}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./img/1.png} 
    \caption{Figure D}\label{fig:tabd}               
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A table with figures}
\label{tab:mytable}
    \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: first one worked I was using environment tabular not tabularx was this the reason?

Comment: No. If you have been used `p{...}` column type, my solution also would work with tabular too.  Columns `c` doesn't allow broke lines in cells. However, notice difference in use of `subfigures` in my answer and your code. In my MWE are not in `tabulr(x)`  environement.