# How to add captions to individual tables inside tabular?

Tags: tables, captions

I have the following code which creates three tables side by side. How do I add a different caption to each of them separately?

```
\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}  
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{11}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{12}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{13}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{14}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{15}$ & $F_2$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{21}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{22}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{23}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{24}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{25}$ & $F_4$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{31}$ & $F_5$    \\
        $S_{32}$ & $F_5$    \\
        $S_{33}$ & $F_5$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{99 most frequent hashtags in the data set.}
\end{table}
```

Comment: you can find your answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15282/tabular-title-above-and-caption-below

Comment: @epcpu The formatting gets messed up using this

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6850/134144

Comment: Your question seems  badly named: what you are asking for is caption for individual tabular inside table.

Comment: The answers prposed using mini pages do work. Nevertheless it seems over complicated. A more general and easy solution would be to load both the caption and subcaption packages (the latter loads the former) and use for each tabular the subtabke evironmemt (as provided by subcaption) ant the `\captionof` command in each subtable.Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383254/33514.

Comment: The main problem is that \caption will use the entire width of the page unless restrained (by a minipage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is not clear (to me), how you like to have captions to your tables, so below are two possible examples:

[image]

in the first is used `tabularx` for spreading tables in line, in the second are used `subtable` environments from `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{11}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{12}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{13}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{14}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{15}$ & $F_2$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{The first table}
    &
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{21}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{22}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{23}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{24}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{25}$ & $F_4$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{The second table}
    &
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{31}$ & $F_5$    \\
        $S_{32}$ & $F_5$    \\
        $S_{33}$ & $F_5$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{The third table}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
or
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{subtable}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{11}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{12}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{13}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{14}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{15}$ & $F_2$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{The first table}
    \end{subtable}
    \hfill
\begin{subtable}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{21}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{22}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{23}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{24}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{25}$ & $F_4$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{The second table}
    \end{subtable}
    \hfill
\begin{subtable}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{31}$ & $F_5$    \\
        $S_{32}$ & $F_5$    \\
        $S_{33}$ & $F_5$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{The third table}
    \end{subtable}
\caption{99 most frequent hashtags in the data set.}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With minipages and the help of the `capt-of` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|}  
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{11}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{12}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{13}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{14}$ & $F_1$    \\
        $S_{15}$ & $F_2$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{21}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{22}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{23}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{24}$ & $F_3$    \\
        $S_{25}$ & $F_4$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Service  & Features \\
        \hline
        $S_{31}$ & $F_5$    \\
        $S_{32}$ & $F_5$    \\
        $S_{33}$ & $F_5$    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \captionof{table}{Caption of first table}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
         \captionof{table}{Caption of second table}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
         \captionof{table}{Caption of third table}
\end{minipage}




\end{document}
```

Comment: You can put more than one \caption inside a table environment.  \captionof is not really needed.